# Given $X \sim \exp(1)$ find the probability density function of $Y = g(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Given $X \sim \text{exp}(1)$ find the probability density function of the derived RV $Y = g(X)$ where $Y$ is:

$$ Y = 
\begin{cases} X & \text{when } X \leq 1 \\ 
\displaystyle \frac {1} {X} & \text{when } X > 1 \end{cases} $$

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABYW8.jpg)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABYW8.jpg)
is my attempt of the problem however i really doubt that it is correct especially because the range of the PDF overlaps as I got $y \leq 1$ when $x \leq 1$ as well as $1/y > 1  \iff  y < 1$ when $x > 1$. If it is correct how do i handle it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve the problem is to do a drawing of the transformation function and realize that

$$\mathbb{P}[Y>y]=F_X\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)-F_X(y)=e^{-y}-e^{-1/y}$$

thus

$$F_Y(y)=1+e^{-1/y}-e^{-y}$$

derivating you get your density...and observe that $y \in(0;1]$

$$f_Y(y)=\left[\frac{e^{-1/y}}{y^2}+e^{-y}\right]\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0;1]}(y)$$

this is the drawing of your pdf

[image]